# Es necesario crear una tabla relacional de categorias por modelo?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un proyecto que tiene 3 modelos y una tabla de categorías

```
|      model a        |
|---------------------|
|                     |

|      model b        |
|---------------------|
|                     |

|      model c        |
|---------------------|
|                     |

|      categories     |
|---------------------|
|                     |
```

Lo que me tiene parado pensando es **si por cada modelo debo tener una tabla relacional como en el ejemplo de abajo o manejo una tabla relacional general que relacione todos los modelos con la el id de categorias**?

```
 |      model a    |  |      model_a_categories        | |      categories     |
 |-----------------|  |--------------------------------| |---------------------|
 |                 |  |                                | |                     |
 
 |      model b    |  |      model_b_categories        | |      categories     |
 |-----------------|  |--------------------------------| |---------------------|
 |                 |  |                                | |                     |
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser un poco más explícito? La necesidad de crear más o menos entidades (que terminarán siendo tablas) depende precisamente de la semántica

Comment: Depende, pero ciertamente no es la manera más natural de resolverlo, lo habitual es una tabla `modelos` y otra `modelos_categoria`

Comment: todo depende del contexto, personalmente tendria 3 tablas y a modelos otra caategorias y una que relacione las primeras 2

Comment: Ósea ya teniendo un modelo hago una tabla que relacione a la tabla categorías y así cada modelo @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende del contexto, personalmente tendria 3 tablas y a modelos otra categorias y una que relacione las primeras 2.

Tabla "modelos":

```
id  nombre      descripcion
1   Modelo A    Este es el modelo A
2   Modelo B    Este es el modelo B
3   Modelo C    Este es el modelo C
```

Tabla "categorias":

```
id  nombre             descripcion
1   Categoria 1       Esta es la categoria 1
2   Categoria 2       Esta es la categoria 2
3   Categoria 3       Esta es la categoria 3
```

Tabla "relacion_modelo_categoria":

```
id  id_modelo   id_categoria
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   2           3
4   3           1
```

En este ejemplo, la tabla "relacion_modelo_categoria" relaciona cada modelo con una o varias categorías. Por ejemplo, el "Modelo A" está relacionado con la "Categoria 1" y la "Categoria 2", mientras que el "Modelo B" está relacionado solo con la "Categoria 3"

Comment: En este caso los modelos ya están creados en sus tablas correspondientes

Comment: que modelos, no se de que hablas

Comment: Las tablas a, b y c las tengo creadas de hace un tiempo. No entendí lo de colocar todo en una tabla llamada modelos

Comment: yo no hice ese comentario, solo te decia que la mejor obcion es con la tabla modelos la tabla categorias y la tabla que relaciona ambas. en simples palabras solo necesitas una tabla relacional